# Mysql Obtaining actual value through FK when Selecting all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, subquery, foreign-key-relationship

I need to `select * FROM sections` and get the column values for every row to fill a `JTable`. My problem is that my `adviserId` column on **section** table is an `INT`

And because I'm getting the result set of every column on every row, I cannot issue a `WHERE` clause. I thought of subquery but since `Id` is different on every row, no predetermined `Id` can be supplied on `WHERE` clause.

So If I run my stored procedure, I get just an `int` value for `adviserId` instead of the teacher's name.

I have **teachers** and **sections** table.

**Teacher**

```
id PK INT
lastName 
firstName 
middleName 
isAdviser 
status
```

**Sections**

```
id PK
name 
adviserId FK-- REFERENCING `id` column ON teacher table
```

What would be the best approach? I hope you can help.

Thanks.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
I've created the final stored procedure based on everyone's suggestion. (THANKS AGAIN all.)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAllSectionsInfo`()
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    s.`name` AS `Section Name`,
    s.`session` AS `Session`,
    CONCAT(t.lastName,',',t.firstName,' ',t.middleName) AS Adviser,
    s.yearLevel AS `Year Level`,
    CONCAT(syStart,'-',syEnd) AS SchoolYear

    FROM sections s 
    INNER JOIN 
    teacher t on s.adviserId = t.id;
END
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM sections s INNER JOIN teacher on s.adviserId = t.isAdviser - Check this will help you

Comment: Just do a join and be done with it.

Comment: It's hardly possible to guess what your problem is. 1. why do you think it's a problem that one of your columns is INT? 2. why does getting results of every column in every row prevent your from using where??

Comment: @Rakesh. `adviserId ` references `id`column, so `s.adviserId = t.isAdviser` is incorrect.

Comment: @Jacobian yes, its my mistake
use it- SELECT * FROM sections s INNER JOIN teacher on s.adviserId = t.id

Comment: @RakeshKumar Thanks for the suggestion. I focused too much on subquery that I failed to think of joins. I sometimes fall into that state where I forget other options. I've updated my question with the solution based on everyone's suggestion. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I also think the same, that a simple `inner join` will do your job. Try the below example..

```
create table JTable as select T.id as Tid,T.lastName,T.firstName,T.middleName,T.isAdviser,T.status,S.id as Sid,S.name,S.adviserId
from Sections as S
inner join Teachers as T on T.id = S.adviserId
```

You can apply `left join` here to make sure that you have all records of **Section** table either related to **Teachers** data or with null data.
So, now the **JTable** will have all the columns in that you have put on the selection list.

Answer (score 0):

Below is solution for db data selection

```
SELECT * FROM sections s INNER JOIN teacher on s.adviserId = t.id
```